# Updating log4j to version 2.12.2 is not working on weblogic deployment 12.1.3 - java7

Tags: java, spring, log4j, weblogic

I updated the log4j lib from version 2.7 to 2.12.2 as Log4j team requested in their website.

```
Users requiring Java 7 should upgrade to release 2.12.2 when it becomes available (work in progress, expected to be available soon).
```

But when deploying in the Weblogic 12.1.3 I am having the following error

```
###<Error> <Deployer> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1639598874181> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "110348212935300" for task "0". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: null
null"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: null
null
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.createModuleException(WebAppModule.java:1824)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:270)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:682)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:98)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.init(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:84)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModule(InitModulesFlow.java:288)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModules(InitModulesFlow.java:301)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.prepare(InitModulesFlow.java:329)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:706)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:237)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:61)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.RedeployOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(RedeployOperation.java:104)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.RedeployOperation.doPrepare(RedeployOperation.java:138)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:233)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:749)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1238)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:252)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:172)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.polulateOneClassInfo(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:240)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.populateClassInfos(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:193)
    at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.<init>(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:44)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.War.initializeClassInfosIfNecessary(War.java:446)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.War.getAnnotatedClasses(War.java:376)
    at weblogic.servlet.utils.WarUtils.isJsfApplication(WarUtils.java:258)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.detectJsfApplication(WebAppModule.java:277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:262)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:682)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:98)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.init(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:84)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModule(InitModulesFlow.java:288)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModules(InitModulesFlow.java:301)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.prepare(InitModulesFlow.java:329)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:706)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:237)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:61)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.RedeployOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(RedeployOperation.java:104)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.RedeployOperation.doPrepare(RedeployOperation.java:138)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:233)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:749)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1238)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:252)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:172)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

I was researching and it seems that some class was compiled in another version that is not supported by weblogic.

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide the complete error stack trace from the weblogic server log file.

Comment: Any error message in the log file about an issue during application deployment ?

Comment: I could not find any other thing that could help me in this. It seems that 2.12.2 is not supported by weblogic somehow. I need to dig deeper on this. For now we decided to mitigate the issue removing JndiLookup class from the 2.7 jar. @EmmanuelCollin

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this issue deploying against Weblogic 12.1.3 after updating log4j to 2.12.4.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic-maven-plugin:12.1.3-0-0:deploy on project xxx: weblogic.Deployer$DeployerException: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Task 23 failed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application xxx-1.0.0_loc_int on AdminServer.
[ERROR] Target state: deploy failed on Server AdminServer
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[ERROR]     at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:41)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.polulateOneClassInfo(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:240)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.populateClassInfos(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:193)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.<init>(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:44)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.War.initializeClassInfosIfNecessary(War.java:446)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.War.getAnnotatedClasses(War.java:376)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.servlet.utils.WarUtils.isJsfApplication(WarUtils.java:258)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.detectJsfApplication(WebAppModule.java:277)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:262)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:682)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:98)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.init(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:84)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModule(InitModulesFlow.java:288)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModules(InitModulesFlow.java:301)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.prepare(InitModulesFlow.java:329)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:706)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:237)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:61)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:208)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:233)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:749)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1238)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:252)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:172)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]     at weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:76)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.Deployer.mainWithExceptions(Deployer.java:63)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.tools.maven.plugins.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:300)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] Caused by: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Task 23 failed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application tub-1.0.0_loc_int on AdminServer.
[ERROR] Target state: deploy failed on Server AdminServer
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
[ERROR]     at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at com.bea.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassInfoImpl.<init>(ClassInfoImpl.java:41)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.polulateOneClassInfo(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:240)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.populateClassInfos(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:193)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.utils.annotation.ClassfinderClassInfos.<init>(ClassfinderClassInfos.java:44)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.War.initializeClassInfosIfNecessary(War.java:446)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.War.getAnnotatedClasses(War.java:376)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.servlet.utils.WarUtils.isJsfApplication(WarUtils.java:258)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.detectJsfApplication(WebAppModule.java:277)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:262)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.init(WebAppModule.java:682)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.init(ScopedModuleDriver.java:162)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.init(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:98)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.init(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:84)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModule(InitModulesFlow.java:288)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.initModules(InitModulesFlow.java:301)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.InitModulesFlow.prepare(InitModulesFlow.java:329)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:706)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:237)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:61)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:208)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:233)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:749)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1238)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:252)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:172)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.report(Jsr88Operation.java:547)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.perform(Deployer.java:140)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.runBody(Deployer.java:88)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115)
[ERROR]     at weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:74)
[ERROR]     ... 24 more
```

Using log4j 2.1 - 2.8.2 doesn't cause this issue. Starting with 2.9.0 the error appears on deploy.

Comment: Did you fix the issue?